# How does python resolve imports (especially in context of django)?

Tags: python, django, import

I am doing a tutorial to get to know Django.
The last chapter I did was this one http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/models.html

I am using a virtual-environment managed via virtualenvironmentwrapper. 
What I was wondering about is, how the imports really work. For example
we have this statement:

```
from rango.models import Category, Page
```

where we work on the file **admin.py** which is located in the same folder **.../rango/** as **models.py** so I would expect

```
from models import Category, Page
```

to be the import statement (which seems to work, too as far as i can test it).
Ok, **.../rango/** contains an **__init__.py** and therefore is considered as package as far as I know but why would I use the longer import-statement over the shorter one?

But most important to me would be:

When I use the shell to see **sys.path** I only get the directories created by my virtualenvwrapper where i would have expected it to contain (besides others) something like

```
[...]/rango/..
```

(the path to the parent-directory of rango).
How does the interpreter know where to search for those modules/packages in the first place?

Comment: What is longer import and shorter import ? Can you explain from your question?

Comment: There is nothing special about Django if you are talking about the import statements. Imports are python's feature not Django's so if you understand import in python then that will be all for this question

Comment: What about reading the fine manual ? https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement (python 2.7.x) or https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html (Python 3.6.x)

Comment: When I say longer I mean rango.models and for shorter the one where I just import models. And ok, it was stupid to mention django in the headline. It is just the context where the question originated. Unfortunately your link doesn't solve my problem. I wouldn't have asked if a simple google-search would have answered my question in a way I am currently able to understand. Example:  "If the module being imported is supposed to be contained within a package then the second argument passed to find_module(), \__path\__ on the parent package, is used as the source of paths." Parent package of what?